# Android - How to access data from the Room database to the Stack Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-room, android-database

I just learned about Android and here I have homework. I tried to make a stack widget which accesses a data from the database Room, here I try to access it but the data does not appear, I am confused about the solution and still do not understand

```
private Context context;
private List<MovieEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();

public StackRemoteViewsFactory(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    new AsyncTask<Context, Void, List<MovieEntity>>() {

        @Override
        protected List<MovieEntity> doInBackground(Context... contexts) {
            AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(context);
            list = database.favoriteDao().getMovies();

            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieEntity> movieEntities) {
            super.onPostExecute(movieEntities);
        }

    }.execute(context);
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.item_widget);

    for (MovieEntity movieEntity : list) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300_and_h450_bestv2" + movieEntity.getPosterPath())
                    .into(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).get();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "error");
        }


        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_item_title, movieEntity.getTitle());
        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image_item_poster, bmp);
    }
    return rv;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not using the `movieEntities` list in `onPostExecute()`

The way `AsyncTask` works is `doInBackground()` is for doing the actual background work (network access, database access, etc...).

Then, whatever you return from this method is passed to `onPostExecute()` which operates on the main thread and is where you should then use it.